# Web service - cache update

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching

I am trying to make a web service that caches its output content.

I have added `[WebMethod(CacheDuration=1800)]`, but the problem is that i want the web service to update its cache automatically after, say 30 min, without any requests to it.

I am using .net with C#. the web service is actually a proxy that gets xml data, parses it and sends it to the client.

How can the web service update its cache after some time period (by itself)?

Comment: Yes. How can the web service update its cache after some time period (by itself)?

Comment: Why cache for 30 minutes in that case? Cache for a day.

Comment: The cache duration is not the problem. The problem is that it takes a long time to get the data, and if you are an unlucky client that opened the page after the cache has been cleared, you'll have to wait. But, if the web service updates the cache like 5 minutes before its expiry, this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [timer classes](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331051599793&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx&ei=TjxWT42cBcLz8gP34aT-CA&usg=AFQjCNFy-htPsHygDtaPUj9KyK9H2cr6pA) to refresh a cached result set - saving it in a field on the class.

This way you can manage the cache instead of IIS.

An alternative to timers is to use the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class - using a `CacheItemUpdateCallback` to refresh the cache automatically once it expires (still leaves a small window where a user might call the method *as* it refreshes - possibly use *two* cache items).

Comment: As per your link, I think, You can not use "System.Windows.Forms.Timer" in web. I tried "System.Timers.Timer" class and used Elapsed event, but it did noy hit the handler. I used the below mentioned code. `System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
                t.Enabled = true;
                t.Interval = 5000;
                t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }`

Comment: my first idea was to use a new thread that sleeps for some time, then starts executing (updates the cache) and then sleeps again. Still, as simple as it sounds, its a nightmare to implement. All the resources that are shared during the update interval must be locked so they can be updated. any suggestions on this?

Comment: anyhow, would you be kind to tell me where should i put the code for the timer??? should it be in the method, or someplace outside?